# Best way to save all actions in an application with Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to save all actions that my staff doing in my application. I could save a report when all function are called, however, I want to save all the actions that was doing in this function.
For example, if you update one field in some form, I would like to save what forms are updated.

**What is the best way to do it? Manual? Is there some library that help me to do it? I did not find any.**

Comment: What is the 'saving' you're after? You could use logging in order to have feedback on what is being done. Python has a well documented `logging` library.

Comment: For example: An member of my staff update a client form. I would like to save: 
Who is it? How many time the user stay in the view? What fields he/she update, save or delete? Method that he/she used (Post or Get)
I think that the best way is do it manually, but I think is there is libraries for help me

Comment: I understand you wish to save a lot of info on what people did, but my question is: what do you mean by 'saving'? Do you want to print it to a standard output? Or save it to a log file for posterity..? What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I would like to save the data in my database for check it whenever I want.

Comment: In that case, how would you model this data? Which kind of database? The basic info you need is what _exactly_ is that you want to store. It is not good practice to store huge amounts of data that may never even be used. Can you give a bit more context to your application? Perhaps a simple logging system would suffice? Managing log files is simple, you can rotate them after a specific time or file size, and get rid of old unnecessary stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The point is that is not my decision, I am a simple developer and I have to do it. The CEO want a view with this info for have control of staff actions. I am just looking for do it faster and better.

Comment: The database is Postgres and it is an internal administration application in Django.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230289/discussion-between-matheus-bruhns-bastos-and-miguel-herreros-cejas).

Comment: Please, post the solution as an answer and mark accordingly. About your new problem/question, please provide a case in which there is an error and detail it in _another_ question, as this one was originally about something already solved.

Comment: The point is that it is not a real problem. It working correctly, but I have ridden in other posts that is not a recommended way for get the request.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution with Signals:

```
 @receiver(post_save, sender=ChargeLogs)
   def create_log(sender, **kwargs):
     import inspect
     for frame_record in inspect.stack():
       if frame_record[3]=='get_response':
           request = frame_record[0].f_locals['request']
          break
       else:
         request = None


   createlogactionsStaff(request,sender,kwargs.get('instance'),kwargs)
```

The way to get it probably will fail in some models or actions (I am not sure).
How can I get it for sure?, considering that createlogactionsStaff is in a view.